# Do a Windows application ifself contain the .NET framework?

Tags: setup-deployment

I have a Windows application which contain a deployer.

1. Does the deployer itself contain a copy of the [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) framework?
   Or do we have to explicitily install it?
   When I check in the solution explorer, it shows the .NET framework under the deployer project under detected dependencies?
2. My Windows application connects to the Internet to validate for a registered user. Do I need to configure some port (or something like that) while I am installing it? Also how do I check which port my application uses to connect to the Internet?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding #1, just as Xstahef said, you need to prerequisite the .NET framework.

You could put the .NET redistributable in your installer, and if you detect that the .NET runtime is not installed then prompt the user to run and install the .NET distributable contained in your installer (that's what we did some time ago, InstallShield provided this functionality for us). But this may not be recommendable: the .NET runtime has grown a lot in size (depending of the version you need to have in your client's machine), and many customers (at least the educated customers) won't trust installing the runtime from your installer. Besides, you may need to check with the legal department in your company before including a third-party component in your installation.

Answer (score 0):

1. It depends on your deploy project ([Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio), [InstallShield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InstallShield)?). But commonly, you need to force the [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) installation (prerequisite option). By default, .NET is not contained in the deployment projects.
2. Here, it depends on the way you want to connect the Internet.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply .
I am using a web service from my windows application then connect and validate.

Comment: if your webservice is on port 80, you will have no problem with firewall (if it's your probelm about port)

Answer (score 0):

1. .NET runs in a [VM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine), so you would need to require the framework be installed in order to actually run it. Much like you need to have [Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash) or [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) for those respective mediums. Microsoft has redistributable packages for the .NET framework. So you could probably incorporate them into your installer. If you're targeting 1.1 or 2.0 most people probably won't need it.
2. So long as you are not trying to get ***in*** to the client machine then you shouldn't need anything special like [UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) to [attempt to] open a port if they are behind a [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) router.

Answer (score 0):

[Xenocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoon_%28software%29) does allow to running such an application on an absolutely clean PC.